# Flutter - Passing calculation as a text to a different screen

Tags: flutter, dart, calculation

I'm new to Flutter and coding in general and I'm building my first simple Fahrenheit to Celsius (and vice versa) temperature convertor app.

What I want my app to do:

The user needs to enter a number value in the text field and click the button. After clicking the button, the user needs to be transferred to a second screen with a simple text widget displaying a result of conversion.

I have already built all of that. My only problem is that the actual result is not displaying on the second screen. Right now, the value which is entered in the text field is just simply passed onto the second screen. It is not doing the calculation. I can display an alert dialog, which works fine and shows the correct calculation, but I just want a simple text on the second screen instead of that and that doesn't work for me.

Screenshots attached to the post.

Can someone help me to solve this? Thanks.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bRGK.jpg)

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:temp_conversion/screentwo.dart';
import 'assets/global.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: TempApp(),
    );
  }
}

class TempApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  TempState createState() => TempState();
}

class TempState extends State<TempApp> {

  String value;
  double input;
  double output;
  bool fOrC;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    input = 0.0;
    output = 0.0;
    fOrC = true;
  }



                                           // SEARCH BAR
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    CupertinoTextField inputField = CupertinoTextField(

      padding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
      onChanged: (text) {
        value = text;
        try {
          input = double.parse(text);
        } catch (e) {
          input = 0.0;
        }
        },

      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(17),
        ),
      ),

      placeholder: "Value in ${fOrC == true ? 'Fahrenheit' : 'Celsius'}",
//      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    );





                                        // (INVISIBLE) APP BAR
    AppBar appBar = AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      elevation: 0,
    );




                                                //RADIO
    Container tempSwitch = Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Fahrenheit", style: textSwitch),
          Radio<bool>(
              groupValue: fOrC,
              value: false,
              onChanged: (v) {
                setState(() {
                  fOrC = v;
                });
              }),
          Text("Celsius", style: textSwitch),
          Radio<bool>(
              groupValue: fOrC,
              value: true,
              onChanged: (v) {
                setState(() {
                  fOrC = v;
                });
              }),
        ],
      ),
    );


                                                  // WHITE CONTAINER AND TITLE
Container whiteContainer = Container(
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40),
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          'Convert it',
          style: titleBar,
        ),
      ],
    ),
    height: 200,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.4),
          spreadRadius: 5,
          blurRadius: 10,
        )
      ],
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
      ),
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
  ),
);




                                            // DESCRIPTION
Container descText = Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, bottom: 15, right: 100),
  child: Text('Write down your value below:', style: description,),
);




                                                  // GO BUTTON
    Container calcBtn = Container(
      child: CupertinoButton(
        child: Text("Go"),
        color: Colors.blue,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24)),
        onPressed: () {

          setState(() {
              fOrC == false
                  ? output = (input - 32) * (5 / 9)
                  : output = (input * 9 / 5) + 32;



          });

          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => screentwo(value : value)
            ),
          );
//          AlertDialog dialog = AlertDialog(
//            content: fOrC == false
//                ? Text(
//                "${input.toStringAsFixed(2)} F : ${output.toStringAsFixed(2)} C")
//                : Text(
//                "${input.toStringAsFixed(2)} C : ${output.toStringAsFixed(2)} F"),
//          );
//          showDialog(context: context, child: dialog);

        },
      ),
    );
                                                  // WIDGET TREE
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      appBar: appBar,
      body: Container(
//        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),    CHANGE THIS IF NOT DISPLAYING CORRECTLY
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[



            whiteContainer,
            descText,
            inputField,
            tempSwitch,
            calcBtn,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

screentwo.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'main.dart';

class screentwo extends StatefulWidget {

String value;
screentwo({this.value});


  @override
  _screentwoState createState() => _screentwoState(value);
}

class _screentwoState extends State<screentwo> {
  String value;
  _screentwoState(this.value);
  @override

  Widget build (BuildContext context) {  //THIS IS SECOND SCREEN
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(value),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: hi there. you did a small mistake by passing the wrong value in the second screen you need to pass the output.tostring() to the second screen not value. value is the value you get as input,

Comment: Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => screentwo(value : output.tostring())
            ),
          );

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked!!

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, just replace the value to output in main.dart.

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => screentwo(value : output)
            ),
          );
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. The thread can be closed now

Comment: @RomanKulikov We don't close 'threads' when a good answer is given. However, you can "Accept" the answer if you feel that it helped.

Comment: You're welcome. If it worked for you, you can "Accept" my answer. @RomanKulikov